# Disprove $P(A\mid B) + P(A\mid\bar{B}) = 1$

Tags: probability, examples-counterexamples

How can I disprove this statement?

$$P(A\mid B) + P(A\mid \bar{B}) = 1$$

I tried giving a counterexample but I'm asked to get to some kind of contradiction using sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You cannot get a contradiction by supposing that this fact holds, because there are indeed cases where it does. It is neither always true, nor always false, and the best you can do is give examples and counterexamples.

Comment: the pope is a dog when it rains and the pope is a dog when it isn't raining

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $P(B) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$. Then, $P(\overline{B}) = 1-P(B) = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}.$

Moreover, using the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability):

$$P(A) = P(B)P(A|B) + P(\overline{B})P(A|\overline{B}) \Rightarrow $$
$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}P(A|B) + \frac{1}{2}P(A|\overline{B}) \Rightarrow $$
$$P(A|B) + P(A|\overline{B}) = 1.$$

As a consequence, you cannot disprove that

$$P(A|B) + P(A|\overline{B}) = 1$$

since there are random variables which satisfy the previous equation.

Answer (score 2):

Take $A$ and $B$ such that $$P(A\cap B)\neq P(A)P(B).$$

For example, $P(A)=0.5$, $P(B)=0.3$ and $P(A\cap B)=0.1$.

Thus, $$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}+\frac{P(A\cap\bar{B})}{P(\bar{B})}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4}{7}\neq1.$$$$

Answer (score 0):

Take $A=\Omega$ then $P(\Omega|B)=1$ and $P(\Omega|\bar B)=1$.